# Remove black background form texture OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on a small project, it is a 2D game. The problem I have is that when I render the texture, it has a black background. I loaded the texture data with stbi and set the format to GL_RGBA in glTexImage2D. The image technically has no background, it is PNG format. How can I remove the background?

There is the code with which I load the texture.

```
int width, height;
int comp;
unsigned char* imageData = stbi_load(filePath.c_str(), &width, &height, &comp, 4);

if ( !imageData ) {
    fmt::print("Fail load image: {}", filePath);
    return false;
}

glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

stbi_image_free(imageData);
```

PS: Sorry for bacd English.

Comment: your code  for loading texture looks fine , the issue may be somewhere else.

Comment: Do you search for [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending). See further [LearnOpenGL - Blending](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending)